# hide pic from someone having mutual friend in facebook

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-timeline

Suppose i posted a photo such that all people can view the pic except Mr X who is the mutual friend with me Mr A. now IF A comments or likes the pic, will Mr X be still able to view the pic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the privacy settings for a photo explicitly exclude someone from seeing it, they will not see it, regardless of whether their friends comment on it